# How can I replace NULL values with matching P_ID for all rows?

Tags: oracle11g, tableau-api, informatica

The dataset which I have has one issue that if I pick data of one patient which is associated with its P_ID, I get all the details of how many drugs he took, how many tests, and what disease he had. But the details provided of one part leaves another part empty. Because of this whenever I try to count drugs taken related to patient id associated with disease id it gives me 1. Below is the sample data:

```
p_id    ds_id   sympton ds_from_date    ds_to_date  dr_id   dosage  dr_from_date    dr_to_date  tt_id   result  tt_date s_id
00047880    0002    Sympton of ALL  1999-1-23   2003-12-31  00096360    7   1999-1-23   2000-1-23   null    null    null    null
00047880    null    null    null    null    00024244    7   2000-1-23   2001-1-23   null    null    null    null
00047880    null    null    null    null    00054795    3   2001-1-23   2002-1-23   null    null    null    null
00047880    null    null    null    null    00063682    4   2002-1-23   2003-1-23   null    null    null    null
00047880    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00796   Result of test  1999-1-23   null
00047880    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00924   Result of test  2000-1-23   null
00047880    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00781   Result of test  2001-1-23   null
00047880    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00314   Result of test  2002-1-23   null
00047880    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    0000973218
00013243    0005    Sympton of Breast tumor 1998-5-20   2003-12-31  00033524    3   1998-5-20   1999-5-20   null    null    null    null
00013243    null    null    null    null    00061642    7   1999-5-20   2000-5-20   null    null    null    null
00013243    null    null    null    null    00079097    5   2000-5-20   2001-5-20   null    null    null    null
00013243    null    null    null    null    00057488    7   2001-5-20   2002-5-20   null    null    null    null
00013243    null    null    null    null    00076684    8   2002-5-20   2003-5-20   null    null    null    null
00013243    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00111   Result of test  1998-5-20   null
00013243    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00583   Result of test  1999-5-20   null
00013243    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00781   Result of test  2000-5-20   null
00013243    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00583   Result of test  2001-5-20   null
00013243    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    00164   Result of test  2002-5-20   null
00013243    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    0000940071
```

I want all the null values to be filled with accurate data. Like:

```
00047880    0002    Sympton of ALL  1999-1-23   2003-12-31  00096360    7   1999-1-23   2000-1-23   00796   Result of test  1999-1-23   0000973218
00047880    0002    Sympton of ALL  1999-1-23   2003-12-31  00024244    7   2000-1-23   2001-1-23   00924   Result of test  2000-1-23   0000973218
00047880    0002    Sympton of ALL  1999-1-23   2003-12-31  00054795    3   2001-1-23   2002-1-23   00781   Result of test  2001-1-23   0000973218
00047880    0002    Sympton of ALL  1999-1-23   2003-12-31  00063682    4   2002-1-23   2003-1-23   00314   Result of test  2002-1-23   0000973218
```

Even if rows does not lessen but I want that somehow those data gets filled up. Its really messing my mind I tried many ways but nothing is working. And because of this if I make a visualization out of it in tableau it shows that person having particular disease has taken only 1 drug and rest are sent to NULL value.[image]

Comment: Is it related to informatica?

Comment: @KoushikRoy yes sir it is

Comment: I think this is complex requirement. For some columns, you have 1 non null value, for some 4 non null values, Is there any pattern or there may be any number of values and they can repeat too? In case you have 2 non null values in a column and 4 non null values in another column, how the data should be displayed.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Like even if it is possible that the number of rows doesn't get lessen but columns get filled. It's not a requirement actually I was just trying to get it working as it will help lessen the work and even the data amount will be less. But now I think that it's not possible maybe.

Comment: If you dont care what values fill the null fields, you can simply use   lookups. Lookup condition will be based on p_id. But you have to create separate lookups for each column. yes, this is inefficient but cant think any other way. Now, if you dont care about the values you use for null column, you can use `coalese` or `nvl`.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I was thinking the same but before proceeding I was thinking that if somehow I can keep track every P_ID and then track of number of rows till DR_ID is not NULL by simultaneously pasting from DS_ID to DS_TO_DATE as they are same for one person. Then moving to TT_ID start pasting all past columns. And finally pasting S_ID in every row. Finally getting distinct out. So is this possible what I think?

Comment: i think it should work. but you still need separate lookups :)

Comment: doing data wrangling in `tableau` is something difficult.  It can however, be done very easily in R.  I may give you a solution, if you want?

Comment: @AnilGoyal sure

Comment: @KoushikRoy yes i think separate lookups are the only way out

Comment: @Av1n4sh (I think Avinash) :) ok tell me R or Excel or both? Please also try to provide a sample data to demonstrate!

Comment: shall i mark it as answer ?

Comment: Avinash asked it.  If not helpful I am happy to delete it

Comment: @AnilGoyal I really appreciate the approach but it will be a bit more time-consuming and I have around 30lac+ rows.

Comment: @Av1n4sh so what do you actually want?  I am asking because you have tagged tableau in question?

Comment: @AnilGoyal Tableau I tagged because if any other way can be possible that this NULL value can be synchronized with those which matched with the same DS_ID. And sir I really like your approach you can keep it here. Because it can be helpful in case of less data.

Comment: So I have shown you in R and Excel,both (after your request)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231270/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-av1n4sh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your data something like this

[image]

#### in R you can do like this

```
df <- read.table(text = "Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Col10
aa  bb  cc  dd  ee  ff  gg  hh  ii  jj
aa  null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
aa  null    kk  ll  null    null    null    null    null    oo
null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    mm", header = T)
#1
df[df == 'null'] <- NA

#2
tidyr::fill(df, everything(), .direction = "down")

  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
1   aa   bb   cc   dd   ee   ff   gg   hh   ii    jj
2   aa   bb   cc   dd   ee   ff   gg   hh   ii    jj
3   aa   bb   kk   ll   ee   ff   gg   hh   ii    oo
4   aa   bb   kk   ll   ee   ff   gg   hh   ii    mm
```

#### in Excel do like this

- Select and replace all `null` with blanks

[image]

- select first blank, enter formula with `=A5` i.e. reference of cell just above it.
- copy this formula
- select all data, `find & replace` -> `go to special` -> `blanks` -> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + V i.e. paste and you're done.

*Note: Tableau isn't meant for data wrangling and I'm sure it can be done through other methods also*

Comment: what is your data source?